# How to enable 'simulate touch events' in Google Chrome by default?

Tags: google-chrome, touch, dom-events

How can I start Google Chrome with dev tools open at startup? I need that because I want to have 'simulate touch events' from the dev tools settings page enabled when I start Chrome. Any ideas? Is there an .ini file for Chrome where one can set a flag or something?

Answer (score 1):

Realize that this is a bit late, but;

When opening the dev-tools settings menu, right next to the "Enable" override checkbox, there is another checkbox saying "Enable on DevTools startup".

Checking this will enable the selected overrides by default when opening the DevTools window.

Hope it helps!